# Search Multiple Arrays simultaneously using Async.Parallel Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, iteration, async.js

I am attempting to search through a variable amount of arrays, returning true when the given value is found in any of them.

I am wondering how I should approach this problem given the arrays could potentially be very large. (I succeeded using Array.prototype.forEach, but as it is 'blocking' I wanted to use the async version)

Below is an abstraction of my current attempt.

```
 var desired_value = 'example'   
 (function(callback) {

     async.each(arry1, function(somevalue, callback) {
       if(somevalue === desired_value) return callback(null, true);
     });

     async.each(arry2, function(somevalue, callback) {
      if(somevalue === desired_value) return callback(null, true);
     });

     async.each(arry3, function(somevalue, callback) {
      if(somevalue === desired_value) return callback(null, true);
     });

 })(function(err, result) {
     return (!result || err) doThis() : doThat();
 });
```

Comment: I removed the call to async.parallel as my code doesn't perform any I/O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the note about async parallel:

> Note: parallel is about kicking-off I/O tasks in parallel, not about
>   parallel execution of code. If your tasks do not use any timers or
>   perform any I/O, they will actually be executed in series. Any
>   synchronous setup sections for each task will happen one after the
>   other. JavaScript remains single-threaded.

https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback

Edit: As for the error, `parallel` takes an array of functions to execute.  However, you're using the results `async.each`, which doesn't return anything.

Edit: To give others an idea of how to execute non-IO code in a non-blocking fashion:

```
function nonblockEach(arr, fn, iterations) {
  if (iterations == undefined) iterations = 1000;
  var count = 0;
  return function(callback) {
    var index = 0;
    function exec() {
      while (count < iterations && index < arr.length) {
        var element = arr[index];
        fn(element, index, arr);
        index++;
        count++;
      }
      if (index < arr.length) process.nextTick(exec);
      else callback();
    }
    process.nextTick(exec);
  }
}
var desired_value = 'example'   
var found = false;
async.parallel([
  nonblockEach(arry1, function(some_value) {
    found = found || (some_value === desired_value);
  }),
  nonblockEach(arry2, function(some_value) {
    found = found || (some_value === desired_value);
  }),
  nonblockEach(arry3, function(some_value) {
    found = found || (some_value === desired_value);
  })
], function(err) {
  return (found) ? something() : anotherThing();
});
```

Not tested, but it gives you the idea.

Comment: I see. I'll pull this for now. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: The Functional side of me tried doing something similar with recursion but it turned out to be a mess. Thanks for the implementation.